# How to (xml) serialize a uri

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have a class I've marked as Serializable, with a Uri property.  How can I get the Uri to serialize/Deserialize without making the property of type string?

Comment: The tags suggest XmlSerializer; actually, you don't need [Serializable] for this - the type just needs to be public.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on one of the answers for [how to serialize `TimeSpan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637933/net-how-to-serialize-a-timespan-to-xml) I ended up with this which works quite well for me and doesn't require the additional property:

```
public class XmlUri : IXmlSerializable
{
    private Uri _Value;

    public XmlUri() { }
    public XmlUri(Uri source) { _Value = source; }

    public static implicit operator Uri(XmlUri o)
    {
        return o == null ? null : o._Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator XmlUri(Uri o)
    {
        return o == null ? null : new XmlUri(o);
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        _Value = new Uri(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(_Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
public class Settings
{
     public XmlUri Uri { get; set; }
}

...
var s = new Settings { Uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com") };
```

And it will nicely serialize and deserialize.

Note: Can't use the trick with the `XmlElement(Type = typeof(...))` attribute as given in another answer in the above linked question as the `XmlSerializer` checks for an empty default constructor first on the original type.

Answer (score 35):

With xml serializer, you are limited - it isn't as versatile as (say) some of the binaryformatter/`ISerializable` options. One frequent trick is to have a second property for serialization:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Uri Uri {get;set;}

[XmlAttribute("uri")]
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string UriString {
    get {return Uri == null ? null : Uri.ToString();}
    set {Uri = value == null ? null : new Uri(value);}
}
```

The two browsable attributes hide it from view (but it needs to be on the public API for `XmlSerializer` to use it). The `XmlIgnore` tells it not to try the `Uri`; and the `[XmlAttribute(...)]` (or `[XmlElement(...)]`) tells it to rename `UriString` when (de)serializing it.

(note that `EditorBrowsable` only applies to code outside the assembly declaring the type)

Comment: Note: There is a small hitch here. The serialization will work, but the de-serialization will fail.

Comment: @SriwanthaAttanayake I think that depends on the Uri.

Comment: Why will it fail to deserialize @SriwanthaAttanayake?

Answer (score 1):

For others who found this question and who didn't like the solutions, there is another more flexible and powerful solution. It's implementation IXmlSerializable interface. This more difficult, but it's worth it. You can create any xml that you would like. The simplest example is:

```
public class Product : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Uri ImageUri { get; set; }

    public virtual System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        Code = reader.GetAttribute("Code");
        Model = reader.GetAttribute("Model");
        Name = reader.GetAttribute("Name");
        if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Image") && reader.HasAttributes)
            ImageUri = new Uri(reader.GetAttribute("Src"));
    }

    public virtual void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Code", Code);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Model", Model);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", Name);
        if (ImageUri != null)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Image");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Src", ImageUri.AbsoluteUri);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

And you get something like this in xml:

```
<PriceContainer Code="314" Model="PP500" Name="NuTone PurePower PP500 Power Unit">
    <Image Src="http://www.thinkvacuums.com/images/nutone-pp500-activac.jpg" />
</PriceContainer>
```

Answer (score -1):

[Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class implements [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) Interface so it should be able to take care of serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe a 3.5 thing?  I get an exception that there is no default constructor when I serialize in 2.0

Comment: That is for *binary* serialization; the question (see tags) is about *xml* serialization

Answer (score -1):

Implement and IDeserializationCallback and use that field on your own.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx

Comment: The tags suggest xmlserializer - which doesn't support these

Comment: From the docs: `Note that this interface is not called when deserializing with the XmlSerializer (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer).`

Answer (score -2):

Uri is already Serializeable, so I don't belive you have to do anything.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(VS.80).aspx

Comment: The tags suggest xmlserializer, so that (alone) doesn't do much