# System.Uri implements ISerializable, but gives error?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to (xml) serialize a uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036492/how-to-xml-serialize-a-uri)

To my knowledge `Uri` implements ISerializable, but throws error when used like this:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Server));
xs.Serialize(Console.Out, new Server { Name = "test", URI = new Uri("http://localhost/") });

public class Server
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri URI { get; set; }
}
```

Works just fine if `Uri` type is changed to `string`.

Anyone knows what is the culprit?

---

### Solution proposed by *Anton Gogolev*:

```
public class Server
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public Uri Uri; 
    
    [XmlElement("URI")]
    public string _URI // Unfortunately this has to be public to be xml serialized.
    { 
        get { return Uri.ToString(); }
        set { Uri = new Uri(value); }
    }
}
```

(Thanks for *SLaks* also pointing out the backwardness of my method...)

This produces XML output:

```
<Server>
    <URI>http://localhost/</URI>
    <Name>test</Name>
</Server>
```

I rewrote it here so the code is visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to be serialized to XML, `Uri` class should have a parameterless constructor, which it doesn't: `Uri` is designed to be immutable. Honestly, I can't see why it cannot be *serialized* without having a parameterless constructor.

To circumvent this, either change `URI` property type to `string`, or add one more property called `_URI`, mark `URI` with `XmlIgnoreAttribute` and rewrite it's `get` method as `get { return new Uri(_URI); }`.

Comment: I added yoursolution to the question, just to make the code visible...

Answer (score 9):

Actually, the best solution would be the reverse - storing the value in a Uri property and accessing it with a string.

For example:

```
public class Server
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("URI")]
    public string UriString { 
        get { return Uri.ToString(); }
        set { Uri = new Uri(value); } 
    }
}
```

This way, it's impossible to set it to an invalid Uri (which would in your code throw an exception in the property getter).  Also, to follow standard .Net casing guidelines, the property should be called `Uri`, not `URI`.

Comment: Yes, thats correct, thanks for that! You don't mind if I added it to the code I wrote to question.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing binary serialization with XML serialization.

XML serialization is a very simple process that saves field values and restores into a new object.

Binary serialization is much more powerful, and allows the object to control serialization behavior.  The [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) interface, which Uri does implement, is only used for binary serialization.

Comment: That indeed was the case. I thought the ISerializable means it's serializable by any serializer (including XML). But I didn't consider this as a answer to *my problem* because my actual problem was to get this XML Serialized.

Comment: Maybe I should change the topic, since this specifically is about xml serialization...

Answer (score 0):

Inner exceptions says:

System.Uri cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Simple answer is that you can't serialize that to xml.