# Store and retrieve image Uri to Isolated Storage wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to save the Uri in isolated storage and retrieve like we do the same for string -> `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Content"] = txt.Text;` OR any other possible way?

```
Uri tileImageUri = new Uri("isostore:/" + args.ImageFileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Debug.WriteLine(tileImageUri.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Uri type is not Serializable because it does not have parameter less constructor.

You can always save the path and construct Uri from it easily. Or you can use the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594368/546896)

Answer (score 0):

Store the "tileImageUri.ToString()" result and create the uri back from the text with "new Uri(string)".