# XmlSerializer - Error serializing an object with a URI property

Tags: c#, .net, uri, xmlserializer

I'm having trouble serializing a class with a `Uri` property.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=There was an error reflecting type 'Foo.Story'.
  // ...
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       Message=There was an error reflecting property 'MyURI'.
```

I would like this property to be serialized. What is a way around this? Should I declare some sort of a converter, and use the string representation of the URI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036492/how-to-xml-serialize-a-uri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Uri` class is not serializable to XML, because all it doesn't have a default constructor and all its  properties are read-only. As a workaround, you can serialize a string instead:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Uri MyURI { get; set; }

[XmlElement("MyURI")]
public string MyURIAsString
{
    get { return MyURI != null ? MyURI.AbsoluteUri : null; }
    set { MyUri = value != null ? new Uri(value) : null; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be `XmlSerializer` ?
`DataContractSerializer` would work:

```
    using (var stream = File.Create(@"c:\Uri.xml"))
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Uri)).WriteObject(stream, new Uri(@"http://www.contoso.com/"));
```

Here is a nice [article](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) that sums up the differences