# How to serialize Pen using XmlElementAttribute.Type property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to serialize some properties defined as `Pen` in my class. As I want to find the simplest and most elegant way to do that, I've tried to apply the solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322461/825024) to the `Pen` type. I only need to serialize the `Color`, `DashStyle` and `Width` properties of a `Pen`, so I've come up with the following class:

```
public class XmlPen {
    private Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1.0F);

    [XmlAttribute]
    public String ColorHtml {
        get { return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(this.pen.Color); }
        set { this.pen.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value); }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public DashStyle Style {
        get { return this.pen.DashStyle; }
        set { this.pen.DashStyle = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public float Width {
        get { return this.pen.Width; }
        set { this.pen.Width = value; }
    }

    public XmlPen() {
    }

    public XmlPen(Pen pen) {
        this.pen = pen;
    }

    public static implicit operator Pen(XmlPen xmlPen) {
        return xmlPen.pen;
    }

    public static implicit operator XmlPen(Pen pen) {
        return new XmlPen(pen);
    }
}
```

According to [the mentionned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322461/825024), I only need to add the following attribute in front of each `Pen`property I want to serialize:

```
[XmlElement(Type = typeof(XmlPen))]
public Pen SomePen { get; set; }
```

But that doesn't work, I get a *InvalidOperationException* when trying to serialize my object:

> System.Drawing.Pen cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

---

My questions are:

1. Why am I getting this error? Doesn't the `[XmlElement(Type = typeof(XmlPen))]` suggests that the `XmlPen` class should be used when (de)serializing the `Pen` property?
2. Is there a trick that would allow me to use this solution on types that do not have a parameterless constructor?

PS: I am not interested in wrapping the `Pen` class in another one if I have to reference this new class everywhere in my code, nor am I interested to add a hidden property in my class to be used when (de)serializing.

Comment: As explained in the accepted answer, this method doesn't work. In the end, I used a [Surrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to serialize my Pen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`Why am I getting this error?`*

because you don't have a `parameter-less` constructor in your Pen class

*`Doesn't the [XmlElement(Type = typeof(XmlPen))] suggests that the XmlPen class should be used when (de)serializing the Pen property?`*

No `Pen` is an independent object and  `Deserialization`  will require a public Parameter-less Constructor in  your Pen  Class

**EDIT**

Comment question

*`Isn't the serializer supposed to use the parameterless constructor of the XmlPen class?`*

No because still your  `public static implicit operator XmlPen(Pen pen)`  require a Pen object that needs to  be constructed at runtime when serializing or deserializing the object