# XmlCodeExporter and nullable types

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, code-generation

`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCodeExporter` generates code (in code CodeDom form) from an XSD schema. But it does it with some quirks. For example an optional element:

```
<xs:element name="Something" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

I would expect this to generate a corresponding code member of type `Nullable<decimal>`, but it actually creates a member of type `decimal`, and then a separate `SomethingSpecified` field which should be toggled separately to indicate a null value. This is probably because the library is from before the introduction of nullable types, but it leads to really inconvenient code.

Is it possible to adjust this code generation, or is there an alternative tool which generate better code in this case?

Edit: I know I can modify the schema and add `nillable='true'`, but I don't want to change the schema to work around limitations of the code generation.

Comment: Try Xsd2Code tool. I used it extensively instead of xsd.exe. Unfortunately I cannot tell you for sure if that specific problem you mention is solved there.

Comment: Have you tried using `nillable='true'` instead of min/max occurs ?

Comment: @Evk: Xsd2Code seems to use XmlCodeExporter under the hood and seem to have the same issue.

Comment: @tchrikch: Yes using nillable="true" in the schema generates nullable properties, but I don't want to have to change the schema to work around a limitation in the code generation, since the schema is the shared contract.

Comment: @JacquesB true, I guess in the worst case you can preprocess xsd schema just before parsing and replace max/min defnitions with `nillable` if feasible

Comment: Are the classes it generates partial? if so you could add a property that is of type decimal?, and reads/writes the SomethingSpecified flag in the getter/setter. Bit of a pain if their are a lot of them, but fine for the odd property.

Comment: @tchrikch: Yes this is what I do now. I'm just looking for a solution where I don't have to work around limitations in the code generation.

Comment: Got an example schema you'd like us to use for testing purposes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The article 
**[Writing your own XSD.exe](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/01/writing-your-own-xsdexe.html)**
 by Mike Hadlow gives a basic framework for creating your own version of `xsd.exe`.  It has the following steps:

1. Import the schemas with [`XmlSchema.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.read(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`XmlSchemaImporter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlschemaimporter(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Generate .Net type(s) and attribute(s) to create using [`XmlCodeExporter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlcodeexporter(v=vs.110).aspx).
3. *Tweak the generated types and attributes as desired*.

   Here you would want to remove the generated `xxxSpecified` properties and promote their corresponding "real" properties to nullable.
4. Generate the final code using [`CSharpCodeProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).

Using this framework, and by experimentally determining what types are actually generated by `XmlCodeExporter` using a debugger, I created the following `CustomXsdCodeGenerator`:

```
public class CustomXsdCodeGenerator : CustomXsdCodeGeneratorBase
{
    readonly bool promoteToNullable;

    public CustomXsdCodeGenerator(string Namespace, bool promoteToNullable) : base(Namespace)
    {
        this.promoteToNullable = promoteToNullable;
    }

    protected override void ModifyGeneratedCodeTypeDeclaration(CodeTypeDeclaration codeType, CodeNamespace codeNamespace)
    {
        RemoveSpecifiedProperties(codeNamespace, promoteToNullable);
        base.ModifyGeneratedCodeTypeDeclaration(codeType, codeNamespace);
    }

    private static void RemoveSpecifiedProperties(CodeNamespace codeNamespace, bool promoteToNullable)
    {
        foreach (CodeTypeDeclaration codeType in codeNamespace.Types)
        {
            RemoveSpecifiedProperties(codeType, codeNamespace, promoteToNullable);
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveSpecifiedProperties(CodeTypeDeclaration codeType, CodeNamespace codeNamespace, bool promoteToNullable)
    {
        var toRemove = new List<CodeTypeMember>();

        foreach (var property in codeType.Members.OfType<CodeMemberProperty>())
        {
            CodeMemberField backingField;
            CodeMemberProperty specifiedProperty;
            if (!property.TryGetBackingFieldAndSpecifiedProperty(codeType, out backingField, out specifiedProperty))
                continue;
            var specifiedField = specifiedProperty.GetBackingField(codeType);
            if (specifiedField == null)
                continue;
            toRemove.Add(specifiedProperty);
            toRemove.Add(specifiedField);

            if (promoteToNullable)
            {
                // Do not do this for attributes
                if (property.CustomAttributes.Cast<CodeAttributeDeclaration>().Any(a => a.AttributeType.BaseType == typeof(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute).FullName))
                    continue;
                var typeRef = property.Type;
                if (typeRef.ArrayRank > 0)
                    // An array - not a reference type.
                    continue;

                // OK, two possibilities here:
                // 1) The property might reference some system type such as DateTime or decimal
                // 2) The property might reference some type being defined such as an enum or struct.

                var type = Type.GetType(typeRef.BaseType);
                if (type != null)
                {
                    if (!type.IsClass)
                    {
                        if (type == typeof(Nullable<>))
                            // Already nullable
                            continue;
                        else if (!type.IsGenericTypeDefinition && (type.IsValueType || type.IsEnum) && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) == null)
                        {
                            var nullableType = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type);
                            var newRefType = new CodeTypeReference(nullableType);
                            property.Type = newRefType;
                            backingField.Type = newRefType;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var generatedType = codeNamespace.FindCodeType(typeRef);
                    if (generatedType != null)
                    {
                        if (generatedType.IsStruct || generatedType.IsEnum)
                        {
                            var newRefType = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(Nullable<>).FullName, typeRef);
                            property.Type = newRefType;
                            backingField.Type = newRefType;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var member in toRemove)
        {
            codeType.Members.Remove(member);
        }
    }
}

public static class CodeNamespaceExtensions
{
    public static CodeTypeDeclaration FindCodeType(this CodeNamespace codeNamespace, CodeTypeReference reference)
    {
        if (codeNamespace == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reference == null)
            return null;
        CodeTypeDeclaration foundType = null;
        foreach (CodeTypeDeclaration codeType in codeNamespace.Types)
        {
            if (codeType.Name == reference.BaseType)
            {
                if (foundType == null)
                    foundType = codeType;
                else if (foundType != codeType)
                {
                    foundType = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return foundType;
    }
}

public static class CodeMemberPropertyExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetBackingFieldAndSpecifiedProperty(this CodeMemberProperty property, CodeTypeDeclaration codeType,
        out CodeMemberField backingField, out CodeMemberProperty specifiedProperty)
    {
        if (property == null)
        {
            backingField = null;
            specifiedProperty = null;
            return false;
        }

        if ((backingField = property.GetBackingField(codeType)) == null)
        {
            specifiedProperty = null;
            return false;
        }

        specifiedProperty = null;
        var specifiedName = property.Name + "Specified";
        foreach (var p in codeType.Members.OfType<CodeMemberProperty>())
        {
            if (p.Name == specifiedName)
            {
                // Make sure the property is marked as XmlIgnore (there might be a legitimate, serializable property
                // named xxxSpecified).
                if (!p.CustomAttributes.Cast<CodeAttributeDeclaration>().Any(a => a.AttributeType.BaseType == typeof(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute).FullName))
                    continue;
                if (specifiedProperty == null)
                    specifiedProperty = p;
                else if (specifiedProperty != p)
                {
                    specifiedProperty = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (specifiedProperty == null)
            return false;
        if (specifiedProperty.GetBackingField(codeType) == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static CodeMemberField GetBackingField(this CodeMemberProperty property, CodeTypeDeclaration codeType)
    {
        if (property == null)
            return null;

        CodeMemberField returnedField = null;
        foreach (var statement in property.GetStatements.OfType<CodeMethodReturnStatement>())
        {
            var expression = statement.Expression as CodeFieldReferenceExpression;
            if (expression == null)
                return null;
            if (!(expression.TargetObject is CodeThisReferenceExpression))
                return null;
            var fieldName = expression.FieldName;
            foreach (var field in codeType.Members.OfType<CodeMemberField>())
            {
                if (field.Name == fieldName)
                {
                    if (returnedField == null)
                        returnedField = field;
                    else if (returnedField != field)
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }

        return returnedField;
    }
}

public abstract class CustomXsdCodeGeneratorBase
{
    // This base class adapted from http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/01/writing-your-own-xsdexe.html

    readonly string Namespace;

    public CustomXsdCodeGeneratorBase(string Namespace)
    {
        this.Namespace = Namespace;
    }

    public void XsdToClassTest(IEnumerable<string> xsds, TextWriter codeWriter)
    {
        XsdToClassTest(xsds.Select(xsd => (Func<TextReader>)(() => new StringReader(xsd))), codeWriter);
    }

    public void XsdToClassTest(IEnumerable<Func<TextReader>> xsds, TextWriter codeWriter)
    {
        var schemas = new XmlSchemas();

        foreach (var getReader in xsds)
        {
            using (var reader = getReader())
            {
                var xsd = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
                schemas.Add(xsd);
            }
        }

        schemas.Compile(null, true);
        var schemaImporter = new XmlSchemaImporter(schemas);

        var maps = new List<XmlTypeMapping>();
        foreach (XmlSchema xsd in schemas)
        {
            foreach (XmlSchemaType schemaType in xsd.SchemaTypes.Values)
            {
                maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportSchemaType(schemaType.QualifiedName));
            }
            foreach (XmlSchemaElement schemaElement in xsd.Elements.Values)
            {
                maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportTypeMapping(schemaElement.QualifiedName));
            }
        }

        // create the codedom
        var codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace(this.Namespace);
        var codeExporter = new XmlCodeExporter(codeNamespace);
        foreach (XmlTypeMapping map in maps)
        {
            codeExporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);
        }

        ModifyGeneratedNamespace(codeNamespace);

        // Check for invalid characters in identifiers
        CodeGenerator.ValidateIdentifiers(codeNamespace);

        // output the C# code
        var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(codeNamespace, codeWriter, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
    }

    protected virtual void ModifyGeneratedNamespace(CodeNamespace codeNamespace)
    {
        foreach (CodeTypeDeclaration codeType in codeNamespace.Types)
        {
            ModifyGeneratedCodeTypeDeclaration(codeType, codeNamespace);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void ModifyGeneratedCodeTypeDeclaration(CodeTypeDeclaration codeType, CodeNamespace codeNamespace)
    {
    }
}
```

To test it, I created the following types:

```
namespace SampleClasses
{
    public class SimleSampleClass
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public decimal Something { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool SomethingSpecified { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("RootClass")]
    public class RootClass
    {
        [XmlArray]
        [XmlArrayItem("SampleClass")]
        public List<SampleClass> SampleClasses { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("SampleClass")]
    public class SampleClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public decimal Something { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool SomethingSpecified { get; set; }

        public SomeEnum SomeEnum { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool SomeEnumSpecified { get; set; }

        public string SomeString { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool SomeStringSpecified { get; set; }

        public decimal? SomeNullable { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool SomeNullableSpecified { get; set; }

        public DateTime SomeDateTime { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool SomeDateTimeSpecified { get; set; }

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280362/most-elegant-xml-serialization-of-color-structure

        [XmlElement(Type = typeof(XmlColor))]
        public Color MyColor { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool MyColorSpecified { get; set; }
    }

    public enum SomeEnum
    {
        DefaultValue,
        FirstValue,
        SecondValue,
        ThirdValue,
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280362/most-elegant-xml-serialization-of-color-structure
    public struct XmlColor
    {
        private Color? color_;

        private Color Color
        {
            get
            {
                return color_ ?? Color.Black;
            }
            set
            {
                color_ = value;
            }
        }

        public XmlColor(Color c) { color_ = c; }

        public Color ToColor()
        {
            return Color;
        }

        public void FromColor(Color c)
        {
            Color = c;
        }

        public static implicit operator Color(XmlColor x)
        {
            return x.ToColor();
        }

        public static implicit operator XmlColor(Color c)
        {
            return new XmlColor(c);
        }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Web
        {
            get { return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color); }
            set
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Alpha == 0xFF) // preserve named color value if possible
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value);
                    else
                        Color = Color.FromArgb(Alpha, ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Color = Color.Black;
                }
            }
        }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public byte Alpha
        {
            get { return Color.A; }
            set
            {
                if (value != Color.A) // avoid hammering named color if no alpha change
                    Color = Color.FromArgb(value, Color);
            }
        }

        public bool ShouldSerializeAlpha() { return Alpha < 0xFF; }
    }
}
```

Using the generic `xsd.exe` I generated the following schema from them:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="SimleSampleClass" nillable="true" type="SimleSampleClass" />
  <xs:complexType name="SimleSampleClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Something" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="RootClass" nillable="true" type="RootClass" />
  <xs:complexType name="RootClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SampleClasses" type="ArrayOfSampleClass" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfSampleClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SampleClass" nillable="true" type="SampleClass" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="SampleClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Something" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SomeEnum" type="SomeEnum" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SomeString" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SomeNullable" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SomeDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MyColor" type="XmlColor" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:long" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="SomeEnum">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="DefaultValue" />
      <xs:enumeration value="FirstValue" />
      <xs:enumeration value="SecondValue" />
      <xs:enumeration value="ThirdValue" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="XmlColor">
    <xs:attribute name="Web" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="Alpha" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="SampleClass" nillable="true" type="SampleClass" />
  <xs:element name="SomeEnum" type="SomeEnum" />
  <xs:element name="XmlColor" type="XmlColor" />
</xs:schema>
```

And, using this schema, I regenerated the following c# classes using `CustomXsdCodeGenerator` with `promoteToNullable = true` and `Namespace = "Question42295155"`:

```
namespace Question42295155 {


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("XsdToClassTest", "1.0.0.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=true)]
    public partial class SimleSampleClass {

        private System.Nullable<decimal> somethingField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public System.Nullable<decimal> Something {
            get {
                return this.somethingField;
            }
            set {
                this.somethingField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("XsdToClassTest", "1.0.0.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=true)]
    public partial class SampleClass {

        private System.Nullable<decimal> somethingField;

        private System.Nullable<SomeEnum> someEnumField;

        private string someStringField;

        private System.Nullable<decimal> someNullableField;

        private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> someDateTimeField;

        private XmlColor myColorField;

        private long idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public System.Nullable<decimal> Something {
            get {
                return this.somethingField;
            }
            set {
                this.somethingField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public System.Nullable<SomeEnum> SomeEnum {
            get {
                return this.someEnumField;
            }
            set {
                this.someEnumField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string SomeString {
            get {
                return this.someStringField;
            }
            set {
                this.someStringField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
        public System.Nullable<decimal> SomeNullable {
            get {
                return this.someNullableField;
            }
            set {
                this.someNullableField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> SomeDateTime {
            get {
                return this.someDateTimeField;
            }
            set {
                this.someDateTimeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public XmlColor MyColor {
            get {
                return this.myColorField;
            }
            set {
                this.myColorField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public long Id {
            get {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("XsdToClassTest", "1.0.0.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
    public enum SomeEnum {

        /// <remarks/>
        DefaultValue,

        /// <remarks/>
        FirstValue,

        /// <remarks/>
        SecondValue,

        /// <remarks/>
        ThirdValue,
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("XsdToClassTest", "1.0.0.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=true)]
    public partial class XmlColor {

        private string webField;

        private byte alphaField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Web {
            get {
                return this.webField;
            }
            set {
                this.webField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public byte Alpha {
            get {
                return this.alphaField;
            }
            set {
                this.alphaField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("XsdToClassTest", "1.0.0.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=true)]
    public partial class RootClass {

        private SampleClass[] sampleClassesField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public SampleClass[] SampleClasses {
            get {
                return this.sampleClassesField;
            }
            set {
                this.sampleClassesField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("XsdToClassTest", "1.0.0.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=true)]
    public partial class ArrayOfSampleClass {

        private SampleClass[] sampleClassField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SampleClass", IsNullable=true)]
        public SampleClass[] SampleClass {
            get {
                return this.sampleClassField;
            }
            set {
                this.sampleClassField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that:

- There are no properties ending in the name `Specified`.
- The properties `Something`, `SomeEnum` and `SomeDateTime` have become nullable.
- The already-nullable `public decimal? SomeNullable { get; set; }` round-trips to `public System.Nullable<decimal> SomeNullable` rather than failing by becoming some dreadful double-nullable `System.Nullable<System.Nullable<decimal>>`.

I then generated the following XML from the initial `RootClass`:

```
<RootClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SampleClasses>
    <SampleClass Id="10101">
      <Something>2.718</Something>
      <SomeEnum>ThirdValue</SomeEnum>
      <SomeString>hello</SomeString>
      <SomeNullable>3.14</SomeNullable>
      <SomeDateTime>2017-02-28T00:00:00-05:00</SomeDateTime>
      <MyColor Web="Maroon" />
    </SampleClass>
  </SampleClasses>
</RootClass>
```

And was able to successfully deserialize it to the generated class `Question42295155.RootClass` without data loss.

Note - this code is lightly tested.  I can re-test with a sample schema if you would like to provide one.

For further information, see [Code Generation in the .NET Framework Using XML Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302301.aspx).