# C# XmlSerializer - Generic custom adapter to handle not valid AllXsd value (like java's XmlJavaTypeAdapter)

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, adapter, xmlserializer

I deserialize an xml using a lot of serializable objects.
I have read that in order to avoid not valid AllXsd value in DateTime, I have to create a helper string property which will handle the input as a string and convert it.
i.e.

```
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

[XmlElement("updateDate")]
public string DateUpdatedAsText
{
    set
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            try
            {
                DateUpdated = DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
    get
    {
        return DateUpdated.HasValue ? DateUpdated.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") : null;
    }
}
```

This is tested and works great. However...

I have over 100 entities that contain DateTime fields in them, some of them more than one, and this solution is not very practical. I will have to implement this in all of them and if I want to change anything in the future I will have to do it again in all of them.
How can I declare a general custom adapter to handle all DateTime types. In Java I can do this:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CalendarXmlAdapter.class)
@Column(name = "updateDate")
private Calendar DateUpdated;
```

and in CalendarXmlAdapter.class specify the marshalling and unmarshalling

Is there a similar solution for C# System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer?

Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

**SOLUTION:**
It is a combination of @dbc comment and @steve16351 answer. I used the CustomDateTime class (with some minor changes in ReadXml, but non important) and in the declaration of the field SomeDate (which remained DateTime? type) I used it like this

```
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "updateDate", IsNullable = true, Type = typeof(CustomDateTime))]
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
```

The convertion takes place smoothly

Comment: `XmlSerializer` doesn't really support surrogate injection.  The closest you can get is the neat trick from [Most elegant XML serialization of Color structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322461/3744182) -- but unfortunately that doesn't work for primitives, and `DateTime` is a primitive.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/V56Yvt, which fails.  Now oddly enough `DateTime?` (nullable datetime) is considered a primitive on some .Net versions, but not others!  Here you can see the trick working on .Net core: https://dotnetfiddle.net/c6F7Ws and failing on .Net 4.5: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nxfeov.

Comment: I combined the annotation of the Color structure to @steve16351 answer and there it goes! I edited my post to provide the combined answer. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IXmlSerializable` if you need more control over the deserialization. While you can't globally provide custom converters for specific types to the `XmlSerializer` to my knowledge, you could write a proxy `DateTime` class like below implementing `IXmlSerializable`, which in my view is more elegant than the solution you have of a string property and a corresponding DateTime property; and would disrupt the codebase less.

Here is an example of such a solution. It is also utilising implicit operators to avoid the need to convert to/from `DateTime?` in your own code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        MyClass myClass = null;
        using (var sr = new StringReader(@"<myXml><updateDate>20181008</updateDate><someProp>Hello, world</someProp></myXml>"))            
            myClass = s.Deserialize(sr) as MyClass;            

        DateTime? myValue = myClass.SomeDate;
        Console.WriteLine($"{myClass.SomeDate}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[XmlRoot("myXml")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("updateDate")]
    public CustomDateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("someProp")]
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }

}

public class CustomDateTime : IXmlSerializable
{
    public DateTime? _dateTime { get; set; }
    private const string EXPECTED_FORMAT = "yyyyMMdd";

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var elementContent = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        _dateTime = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(elementContent) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.ParseExact(elementContent, EXPECTED_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (!_dateTime.HasValue) return;
        writer.WriteString(_dateTime.Value.ToString(EXPECTED_FORMAT));
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime? (CustomDateTime input)
    {
        return input._dateTime;
    }

    public static implicit operator CustomDateTime (DateTime input)
    {
        return new CustomDateTime() { _dateTime = input };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_dateTime == null) return null;
        return _dateTime.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good suggestion. I made some changes to your code and edited my post to provide the complete workaround. Thank you very much