# C# How to xml serialize complex type as a xml attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I want to use XmlSerializer to serialize a class, typical stuff.
My ONE difference is I want to serialize a custom object "ComplexType" as as attribute, not a child element.

I've seen other stack overflow questions and the answers say it's not possible. I know that's wrong.

The error is like:

> "XmlAttribute/XmlText can not be used to encode complex types."

--or--

> "XmlAttribute/XmlText can not be used to encode types implementing
>   IXmlSerializable."

Simply change myfield from ComplexType to DateTime and it works fine. DateTime is definitely complex, so I just need to know what to change in the class or attributes.

ex:  YES

```
<Container myComplexType="specialencoding" />
```

ex:  NO

```
<Container>
   <myComplexType>specialencoding</myComplexType>
</Container>
```

-- See how much nicer the first one is... I want that one.

-- Code is like this...

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Container")]
public class Container
{
  [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="myComplexType")]
  public ComplexType myfield = new ComplexType();
}


public class ComplexType
{
    public ComplexType(){}
    public ComplexType(string encoding){}
    public override string ToString() {return "specialencoding";}
}
```

If I implement ComplexType : IXmlSerializable, I get the second error message above.

Basic serializer used:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));
serializer.serialize("outfile.xml", new Container());
```

Comment: The Xml Attribute is a string.  When you make the XmlAttribute a DateTime is becomes a string with double quotes.  If it was complex then there would not be quotes around the DateTime.

Comment: Right, I can convert my type to/from a simple string so I'd like to be able to behave like DateTime and write to an attribute - with quotes.

Comment: *I've seen other stack overflow questions and the answers say it's not possible. I know that's wrong.* - can you share the answers that didn't meet your requirements, so we don't duplicate effort?

Comment: The schema type xs:dateTime is a simple type, not a complex type. A complex type in XSD is one that contains elements as well as character content. Simply having an internal microsyntax does not make it complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        private ComplexType _myfield = new ComplexType();

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "myComplexType")]
        public string myfield {
            get { return _myfield.ToString();}
        }
    }
    public class ComplexType
    {
        public ComplexType(){}
        public ComplexType(string encoding){}
        public override string ToString() {return "specialencoding";}
    }
```

Comment: Right, that was the answer in the other questions. If I've got a bunch of attributes, I don't want to have to do 2x the code, and the same goes for adding/removing fields.  DateTime can do it just fine, so what's going on with it?

Comment: To be serialized by `XmlSerializer`, the property `myfield` must be read/write.

Comment: @extracrispy - from the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks): *You can assign the XmlAttributeAttribute only to public fields or public properties that return a value (or array of values) that can be mapped to one of the XML Schema definition language (XSD) simple types ...  See the [`DataType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2) property for a list of XSD types and how they are mapped to.NET data types.*

Comment: @extracrispy - and from the docs from [`XmlAttributeAttribute.DataType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks), only known .Net primitives get mapped to XSD simple data types.  Mapping an arbitrary type by using its `ToString()` is not documented to be implemented.

Comment: @dbc Oh, "XSD" simple types. I misread the original docs and thought it was C# simple / primitive types. Wow, ok. Maybe there is some way to accomplish it anyway with some implicit conversion operators?

Comment: @extracrispy - don't think so, the trick from [Most elegant XML serialization of Color structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322461/3744182) doesn't seem to work, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/0rT1Sm

Comment: You do not need the ComplexType class.  You can put all the code into the get/set public property and add any additional variables as private in the main class provided your XmlAttribute is a string.