# Serializable object with readonly members?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have this set of code, but what I'd really like is to make x and y readonly public, or public only with a getter exposed. Normally in C++ you'd make the serializer a friend class. Is there an equivalent trick in C#?

```
public struct z
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public z(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<z> b = new List<z>();
        b.Add(new z(3, 4));
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer w  = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<z>));
        System.IO.StringWriter x = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        w.Serialize(x,b);
        System.IO.StringReader y = new System.IO.StringReader(x.ToString());
        List<z> c = (List<z>)w.Deserialize(y);
        Console.WriteLine(b[0].x);
        Console.WriteLine(c[0].x);
    }
}
```

Comment: public int x { get; }

Comment: Ah, oh, ok. So get and sets aren't really methods (eg, not invoked with `()` but something different?

Comment: getters and setters from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

Comment: Wait, then the serialization still doesn't work.

Comment: Why doesn't this give a compiler error or warn?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Because `List<>` implements `ICollection`, you need to set your class to use private fields and public properties, as public properties are not going to be serialized. To keep things simple you could use an array instead. More on [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization#serializing-a-class-that-contains-a-field-returning-a-complex-object)

Comment: List<> is O(1) insert and array is O(n)?

Comment: Is this the equivalent of a StandardLayoutType which can be memcpy'd vs a non-StandardLayoutType?

Comment: there is an interesting QA on another stack overflow site about that. I only know some basic instructions about C/C++ so I can’t say about the comparison against StandardLayoutType you’ve mentioned. [Link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/221892/should-i-use-a-list-or-an-array) bottom line, best performance depends on what you need to do with your collection. Fixed length (or at least not varying much)? Go for Array. Variable size? Go for List<>

Comment: There is no equivalent of the c++ `friend class` concept in C#. So any standard deserializer won't be able to write on public properties, which only expose a getter. And it surely won't be able to write on private or protected memers.

Comment: Closest equivalent would be to replace the `z` struct with a DTO that supports implicit conversion from and to the "real" type, see [Most elegant XML serialization of Color structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3280362/3744182).   But other serializers support different mechanisms.