# Using ISerializable breaks serialization for previously supported types

Tags: c#, iserializable

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a custom class I have that has a `System.Windows.Media.Color` property. It wasn't working because `Color` doesn't have the `[Serializable]` Attribute. Based on some other articles, I decided to implement `ISerializable`, which would let me define custom serialization logic for the Color type.

Color now gets serialized properly, but now my other properties (bytes, floats, strings) are not being serialized. Do I really need to define explicit serialization logic for every individual property when I implement `ISerializable` even if they were already supported in the first place?

```
        #region Serialization
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            string colorString = new ColorConverter().ConvertToString(_RgbColor);
            info.AddValue("System.Windows.Media.Color", colorString, typeof(string));
        }
        public AbstractColorModifier(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            string colorString = (string)info.GetValue("System.Windows.Media.Color", typeof(string));
            _RgbColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(colorString);
        }

        #endregion Serialization

        #region Properties
        private Color _RgbColor = Colors.Black;
        public Color RgbColor {
            get { return _RgbColor; }
            set
            {
                if (_RgbColor != value) {
                    _RgbColor = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("RgbColor");
                }
            }
        }

        private byte _ByteColor = 0;
        public byte ByteColor {
            get { return _ByteColor; }
            set { ... }
        }
        private float _FloatColor = 0;
        public float FloatColor {
            get { return _FloatColor; }
            set { ... }
        }
        #endregion Properties
```

I would have expected the `byte` `float` and other properties that were working before to keep working. Is there some way I can avoid explicitly handling their serialization?

Comment: Try handling custom property inside the get/set instead of creating a custom serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, you need to serialize everything if you ask explicitly for it using `ISerializable`.

To get that fixed, you got 2 very simple solutions now:

**Solution 1**
Provide the serialization for *all* types you want to have serialized

**Solution 2**
Remove `ISerializable` and add a [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to your `Color` Property. Also add some serialization-only property like this:

```cs
public string ColorSerialized
{
    get => new ColorConverter().ConvertToString(_RgbColor);
    set => _RgbColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 is a nice approach.

Comment: There would be some neater trick if OP was using the XmlSerializer etc. instead :) can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280362/most-elegant-xml-serialization-of-color-structure and "abuses" some `implicit operator`

Comment: Yep this is the one. Ive never seen those get/set lambdas before.. apparently theyre called expression-bodied members. Are they just a cleaner syntax for `get { return new ColorConverter().ConvertToString(_RgbColor); }`?

Comment: Yes, they are. Also allowed for methods since iirc C#7.0 `int function() => 1`

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization):

> When GetObjectData is called during serialization, you are responsible
>   for populating the SerializationInfo provided with the method call.

In other words, you are responsible for serialising (and de-serialising) **all** of the data you are interested (not just `Color`).

Comment: But is there any way to delegate the serialization of the already recognized properties? Its not a huge hassle here as theres only 3 other properties, but there are bigger classes and rewriting pre-existing functionality for dozens of properties seems unnecessary just to get one unsupported type to serialize properly.

Comment: I suppose I could use a string field instead of a Color and just wrap that in a Color type get/set property that does the conversion.. maybe that would be a better solution that implementing ISerializable?

Comment: `But is there any way to delegate the serialization of the already recognized properties?` No. As per my answer you need to do them **all** @Olli.