# Can't serialize Timespan value

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, time

I have to keep time in that format **"00:00:23.123213".**

So I have tried to use `Timespan`

```
  [Serializable()]
    public class Item
    {
        public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
```

But this field is always **empty** in the file.

```
var test = new ContentItems();
 var item2 = new Item();
            item2.ContentType = ContentTypes.Paragraph;
            item2.Data = "Create a new XmlSerializer instance with the type of the test class.";
            item2.DataType = DataTypes.Text;
            item2.Start = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);
            item2.End = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9);
            test.Items.Add(item2);

            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Projects\1.xml"))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentItems));
                serializer.Serialize(writer, test);
                writer.Flush();
            }
```

My Question: ***Which type is better to serialize Time in .NET?***

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes I did it like `item1.Start = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);`

Comment: TimeSpan is definitely serializable, though,

Comment: @Metropolitan a) which serializer do you use? b) it can not be empty since it is not nullable.

Comment: @I4V I have updated my question. Take a look pls.

Comment: Are both Start and End empty?

Comment: @tkeE2036 Yes, both are empty.

Comment: But other things like Data, DataType, and, ContentType are not?

Comment: @tkeE2036 No. They are ok 100%

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637933/net-how-to-serialize-a-timespan-to-xml