# TimeSpan[] XmlSerialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have field `public TimeSpan TimeSpanField` in myClass. I create instance of the myClass and fill field. Next I want to serialize it to XML and deserialize back to the object. I Know that Microsoft have problems with TimeSpan serialization therefore I found the answer [How to serialize a TimeSpan to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637933/net-how-to-serialize-a-timespan-to-xml) and use it. 
ok! It works good. But How to make similar for `public TimeSpan[] TimeSpanArrayField`. the indexer(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in this case didn't help.

Code for`public TimeSpan TimeSpanField`

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan TimeSpanField;

    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlElement(DataType = "duration", ElementName = "TimeSpanField")]
    public string TimeSpanFieldString
    {
        get
        {
            return XmlConvert.ToString(TimeSpanField);
        }
        set
        {
            TimeSpanField = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ?
                TimeSpan.Zero : XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Convert it's value into something what you can serialize.

Comment: you could always just serialize a timespan to a long[] where it stores the ticks. You can then convert it back to a TimeSpan with the ticks constructor.

Comment: @CathalMF, I convert TimeSpan to string and back, it works good.
i want to make similar for Timespan array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public TimeSpan[] TimeSpanArrayField;

    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlElement(DataType = "duration", ElementName = "TimeSpanField")]
    public string[] TimeSpanFieldString
    {
        get
        {
            string[] strings = new string[TimeSpanArrayField.Length];
            for (int number = 1; number <= TimeSpanArrayField.Length; number++)
                strings[number - 1] = TimeSpanArrayField[number - 1].ToString();
            return strings;
        }
        set
        {
            TimeSpanArrayField = new TimeSpan[value.Length];
            for (int number = 1; number <= value.Length; number++)
                TimeSpanArrayField[number - 1] = TimeSpan.Parse(value[number - 1]);
        }
    }
```